# Adding a Route to the base URL of plural Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In Ruby on Rails, is there a way to add another RESTful action to the base URL of a plural resource? I'm looking for something like this:

```
resources :groups do
  resources :users do
    put on: :base, to: 'users#update_all'
  end
end
```

Which would generate the route: `[PUT] groups/:group_id/users => users#update_all`

I've already tried doing this:

```
resources :groups do
  resources :users
  put 'users', on: :member, to: 'users#update_all'
end
```

But that doesn't preserve the value of `params[:group_id]` in the controller.

Comment: FYI, this is a contrived example. My actual set up is somewhat more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    put '' => 'users#update_all' ## PUT /users
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

It would be recommended to do this though:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    put 'update_all' ## PUT /users/update_all
  end
end
```

Both route to the update_all action of the users controller.

**RESOURCES**

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Comment: Thanks. The reason I want the route to be for `/groups/:group_id/users` is that I wanted it to be consistent with the default routes for Rails resources. In Rails, `[PUT] /groups/:group_id/users/:id` points to the `users#update` action, so why wouldn't `[PUT] /groups/:group_id/users` point to the `users#update_all` action?